# pandas replace values in reference to a user input

Tags: python, pandas

I am stuck a little bit, hope you can help me,

I want to replace a value in a pandas df according to a input

Pandas df contains 3 string columns and the default value for category is always 1

| Area | Name | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | Tom | 1 |
| Finance | Laura | 1 |
| Finance | An | 1 |
| Ops | Roger | 1 |

I have a dict= {'finance':'2' ,'sales':'3' ,'ops':'4'}

And if user inputs for example

selection='Finance'

The df should look for all the rows that have 'finance' in the column Area and replace the default Category of 1 for its corresponding value in the dict (in this case 2)

| Area | Name | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | Tom | 1 |
| Finance | Laura | 2 |
| Finance | An | 2 |
| Ops | Roger | 1 |

Also, if user inputs a list: selection=['Finance','Sales'], it should change both:

| Area | Name | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sales | Tom | 3 |
| Finance | Laura | 2 |
| Finance | An | 2 |
| Ops | Roger | 1 |

how could I do this?, i tried with combination of iloc and replace but no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy's `where` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# reproducible example
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Area'] = ['Sales','Finance','Finance','Ops']
df['Name'] = ['Tom','Laura','An','Roger']
df['Category'] = [1,1,1,1]
d = {'finance':2 ,'sales':3 ,'ops':4}

selection = input("Please type in what areas you are searching for:")
# assumes the user is typing in multiple areas split by space
selection = selection.lower().split(" ")
# loop through each selection and change the category
for s in selection:
# takes care of searches that aren't in the dictionary
    if s in d.keys():
        df['Category'] = np.where(df['Area'].str.lower()==s,d[s],df['Category'])
```

For example, if the user types in "ops Finance", the output is

```
    Area    Name    Category
0   Sales   Tom     1
1   Finance Laura   2
2   Finance An      2
3   Ops     Roger   4
```

Comment: will this work if input value is not one of the values in the dictionary?

Comment: Should do, try it and let me know.

Comment: ran your code and it gave me this: Please type in what areas you are searching for:finance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/User/xxxx/stackoverflow-XXX.py", line 16, in <module>
    df['Category'] = np.where(df['Area']==s,d[s],df['Category'])
KeyError: 'finance'

Comment: I think it still wont work for `finance`. It will work for `Finance`. In the `if s in d:`, change it to `if s.capitalize() in d` and in the selection use `d[s.capitalize()]`. In other words, convert s to capitalize version. Then check for dict and replace

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. i thought you *didn't* want it to work unless the user types in the exact wording. I'll change it so caps doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value in the list is part of the dictionary, if so, you can use the iloc option to lookup that value and replace it with new value.

Here's the full code:

```
c = ['Area','Name','Category']
d = [['Sales','Tom',1],
['Finance','Laura',1],
['Finance','An',1],
['Ops','Roger',1]]

dct = {'finance':'2' ,'sales':'3' ,'ops':'4'}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)

selection = ['Finance','Sales']

#the if statement will ensure selection = 'Finance' gets converted to a list
#that way the for loop is not impacted
if isinstance(selection,str): selection = [selection]

for cat in selection:
    if cat.lower() in dct:
        df.loc[df['Area'] == cat, 'Category'] = dct[cat.lower()]

print (df)
```

The output for these are:

```
Input : selection = 'Finance'
```

Output is:

```
      Area   Name Category
0    Sales    Tom        1
1  Finance  Laura        2
2  Finance     An        2
3      Ops  Roger        1
```

Input : selection = ['Finance','Sales']

Output is :

```
      Area   Name Category
0    Sales    Tom        3
1  Finance  Laura        2
2  Finance     An        2
3      Ops  Roger        1
```

If you decide to get the input from the user through an input statement, then you add this code (and replace the assignment):

Replace this code:

```
selection = ['Finance','Sales']
if isinstance(selection,str): selection = [selection]
```

with this code:

```
sel = input('What\'s the selection critiera :')
selection = [s.capitalize() for s in re.split(r' |,',sel) if s != '']
```